# How to create 'assets.bin' file to save and read multiple images of my game?

Tags: java

Basically create an algorithm that saves and **read** several 32x32 sprites in a '.spr' file.
How to read and get buffered image from this **example**:

```
ArrayList<FileInputStream> images = new ArrayList();
   images.add(new FileInputStream(new File("Koala.jpg"))); 
   images.add(new FileInputStream(new File("Desert.jpg")));
   images.add(new FileInputStream(new File("Hydrangeas.jpg")));
   int i = 0;

   File binFile = new File("assets.spr");
   FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(binFile);
   ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(output);

   for(FileInputStream img : images){  
        outputStream.writeUTF("id: " + i);
        int byteRead;
        while((byteRead = img.read()) != -1) {
              outputStream.writeByte(byteRead);
        }

        i++;
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving Multiple Images in a Single File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115777/saving-multiple-images-in-a-single-file)

Comment: No! I need to read the content of file generated from posted code.

Comment: Can you make any assumption about the file to be included in the `assets.spr` file? Do the files always have the same fixed file size which doesn't change? Can you make assumptions about the file type to be added? Also, please [edit] your question to include the source codes you have tried to read the inner files from the "assets.spr" file and write what the problems with these source codes were.

Comment: I will save 32x32 '.png' files.
The code I posted is writing the images from an array into the '.spr' file, but I don't know how to convert the file into an inputstreams array back.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have tried to read the inner files from the "assets.spr" file and write what the problems with these source codes were. Stack Overflow is not a coding service.